# Ranking text based on keywords provided

Tags: java

I have a set of Strings and a set of keywords.

Example 
String 1 : Oracle and Samsung Electronics have reportedly forged a new partnership through which they will work together to deliver mobile cloud services. In a meeting last Thursday, Oracle co-CEO Mark Hurd and Shin Jong-kyun, head of Samsung Electronics’ mobile

String 2 : This is some random string.

Keywords : Oracle,Samsung

The function should return String 1 as the one having highest rank. I can search each strings for each keywords, but it will take too much time as there will be lot of strings and a huge set of keywords.

Comment: Roughly how bis is your set of strings and how many keywords do you have?

Comment: maybe a 500 strings and a 50 keywords

Comment: 50 doesn't seem that huge, are you sure that iterating over strings and keywords will be too slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data structure that maps each term that appears in any of the strings to all strings it appears in.

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> keyword2stringId;
```

If a string contains the same keyword multiple times, you could simply add it to the `List` multiple times, or -- if you prefer -- use a slightly different map which allows you to also keep a count:

```
Map<String,List<Pair<Integer,Integer>>> keyword2pair; // pair = id + count
```

Then for each keyword, you can look up the relevant strings and find the ones with the highest overlap, for instance like so:

```java
// count the occurrences of all keywords in the different strings
int[] counts = new int[strings.length];
for (String keyword : keywords) {
     for (Integer index : keyword2stringId.get(keyword)) {
         if (index != null) {
             counts[index]++;
         }
     }
}

// find the string that has the highest number of keywords
int maxCount = 0; 
int maxIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
    if (counts[i] > maxCount) {
        maxCount = counts[i];
        maxIndex = i;
    }
}

// return the highest ranked string or 
// 'null' if no matching document was found
if (maxIndex == -1) {
    return null;
} else {
    return strings[maxIndex];
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can compute your map *offline* (that is, only once) and then use it again and again for different queries.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should try some search engine or search library like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

> Lucene Core, our flagship sub-project, provides Java-based indexing
>   and search technology, as well as spellchecking, hit highlighting and
>   advanced analysis/tokenization capabilities.
>
> Solr is the popular, blazing-fast, open source enterprise search
>   platform built on Apache Lucene™.

Both of this stuff have support to do what you need to do - to search for some keywords and rank them.

Comment: Lucene Core looks like a huge library. Is there a small library I can use as jar?

Comment: For simple cases, Lucene could be used as a one jar it wouldn't be that hard to do that, especially with the help of Maven

Answer (score 0):

This program can't be less than *O(n) complexity*, that is, you have to check each word of the string with each keyword.

Now, the only think you can do is perform the check over each string all at once:

```
public int getRank(String string, String[] keyword) {
    int rank = 0;
    for (String word : string.split(" "))
        for (String key : keyword)
            if (word.equals(key))
                rank++;
    return rank;
}
```

In this easy example, `rank` is an `int` increased each time a keyword occurs in the string. Then fill an array of ranks for each string:

```
String[] strings = new String[]{"...", "...", "...", "...", ...};
String[] keyword = new String[]{"...", "...", "...", "...", ...};

int[] ranks = new int[stringsNumber];
for (int i = 0; i < stringsNumber; i++)
    ranks[i] = getRank(strings[i], keyword);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're really looking for is [TF/IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) - Term Frequency/Inverse Document Frequency.  The link provided should give you the information you need, or alternatively as @Mysterion has pointed out, Lucene will do this for you.  You don't necessarily need to deploy a complete Lucene/Solr/ElasticSearch installation, you could just make use of the classes you need to roll your own